# Azure B2C OpenID delegate authentication to Azure AD

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, openid, azure-ad-b2c

I followed this tutorial https://victorvillarv.com/en/2019/08/28/how-to-create-an-azure-ad-b2c-directory-and-enable-openid-to-delegate-authentication/

to delegate the authentication of my B2C Users back to Azure AD, where the users were created.
Microsoft announced the new urls with 2bclogin.com.

My Azure Domain and my B2C Domain are the same domain: b2ctestexample.onmicrosoft.com in this tenant I opened a new B2C Azure AD

Will this still be working if I add an identity Provider in Azure B2C App with the url:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/b2ctestexample.onmicrosoft.com/.well-known/openid-configuration?
after the 4th of December? (when it's deprecated)

I configured some Claim Policy Mapping and AD Extensionattributes in an App in the AAD (not B2C) which will be passed in the OAuth ID Token, and I need these when logging in. Can I pass them over to the B2C Apps?

Thanks, 
Patrick

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will work for a while until it is retired, the [doc](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/updates/b2c-deprecate-msol/) mentions that the existing tenants need to move onto B2Clogin.com before that date, and all functionality will remain the same on the B2Clogin.com endpoint. To avoid any future disruption on your service it is recommended to change to new URL while both URL's are working.

Regarding openId-configuration, a B2C application should use new url https://your-tenant-name.b2clogin.com/tfp/your-tenant-ID/policyname/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration as per this [reference](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/16505). so that your application can get right information that is applicable for the policy name passed in the URL.

Comment: Thank you for your question. But does the URL: 
https://login.microsoftonline.com/b2ctestexample.onmicrosoft.com/.well-known/openid-configuration

of the Azure AD stay to authenticate against it? So the B2C App can authenticate against AzureAD (Azure AD and B2C App have are in the same Tenant)

Comment: in the url above b2ctestexample can be a b2c tenant, or has it to be a regular Azure AD Tenant?

It's for authentication and for getting attributes from this app

Comment: The authentication url will be deprecated for your B2C app on Dec 4 2020 as mentioned in the documentation : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/updates/b2c-deprecate-msol/  So, Your B2C app needs to move to B2Clogin.com for authentication to avoid any service disruptions in future. As per the above documentation, it is not mentioned that login.microsoftonline.com, would continue to work for b2c app beyond that date for the tenants created before feb 2020.